# Is it possible to save to disk the past emails in Microsoft Mail?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I am using Windows 8.1 with the Microsoft Mail program and a Hotmail.Com account. Is it possible to save to disk the past emails that I've kept?

I can't find them, other than some at C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Packages\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\Indexed\LiveComm\9ccfaac5bc134954\120712-0049\Mail\1.

My laptop came with "Live Mail" but within a month of purchase I was told by M/S to replace it with "Mail"

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of your account? POP, IMAP or Exchange?

As I know, Microsoft Mail app seems does not support export emails to local disk so far. As a workaround, if you are using IMAP or Exchange email account, you could add your email account to Microsoft Outlook. Emails will be synced to your Outlook, and then you could export or archive old items to your local disk.